# Protect background procces against signal

Tags: c, shell, unix, signals

I need to implement jobs control in my own shell, but when i have background process and I kill the foreground process with ctrl-c, both are killed by sigint

In order to protect process I put itself in the new process group

```
if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
{
  setpgid(0, 0);
  ...
}
```

But now, when I execv 'cat', it is stopped by sigttin, because it can't read stdin and I don't find how give it right or do something else

If you need some information about part of my code or beautiful cats picture I can give it.

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't "protect" you should *handle*

Comment: It is hard to tell what you want.  Maybe you need to code a daemon.  If you read this paper and take the code from it AFTER you read it - things may get better: http://cjh.polyplex.org/software/daemon.pdf